# Origin and spelling of (multi)collinear/colinear

Tags: terminology, multicollinearity, etymology

Multico**ll**inear and multico**l**inear both appear to be used in scientific literature, although the former appears to be a lot more popular and is also the name of the tag here. I figured there must be a single spelling of colinear/collinear which is more correct, but that is also spelled both ways.

Two questions about this:

1. Which is more correct? Is there some different meaning implied by the extra L?
2. If not, why is multico**ll**inear used more frequently?

It doesn't seem intuitive to me that the double L version is more popular. I interpreted its definition as 'sharing linearity' with the outcome and hence the 'co-' prefix. What did the statistician who coined the term have to say about this?

Comment: Wasn't sure this was on-topic, but I came across this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/153526/176202

Comment: "Multicollinear" is a barbarism in the first place, because the "multi" is completely superfluous.  (Statistics never considers the case of a single vector being collinear, because the only possibility is that it's the zero vector, which cannot play any effective role in a linear model.)  Looking up dictionary definitions of "collinear" and "colinear" therefore will provide some authoritative insight into their distinctions and origins.

Comment: @whuber I  seem to recall having this conversation before. (+1) Of course the multi is redundant as collinearity is collective and common to all lines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Collinear* follows the model of *collaborate*, *collide*, &c.: the *m* of the Latin prefix *com-* ("together") is assimilated to the initial *l* of the Latinate stem (cf. *commiserate*, *contemporary*, *coæval*, *corrode*). It's pronounced with the stress on the second syllable, & therefore an indeterminate vowel or at most a short *o*.

An excuse for *colinear* might be that you're treating *linear* as a native word, following the model of *copilot*, *co-worker*, &c.—cases in which the prefix is reduced to *co-* irrespective of the initial letter of the stem.<sup>†</sup> I imagine people who write it thus also pronounce it with at least a secondary stress on the first syllable, & with a long *o*.

*Pace* [@Carl](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/319248/17230) I don't think a general predilection among the British for writing double *l* has much to do with it, though a preference for more traditional word-forms might. Counts of occurrences in published works from [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams) suggest that *colinear* & its derivatives are disfavoured only slightly less in U.S. than in British English (an odds ratio of 1.4 over 1999 – 2008).

```
library(ngramr)
#define word list & corpora
words <- "collinear, colinear, collinearity, colinearity, multicollinear, multicolinear, multicollinearity, multicolinearity"
corpora <- c("eng_gb_2012", "eng_us_2012")
# fetch word counts
dd <- ngram(words, corpora, year_start = 1999, smoothing = 0,  count = T, tag = NULL, case_ins = TRUE)
# reduce derivatives
dd$stem <- factor(gsub("multi|ity", "", tolower(dd$Phrase)))
# tabulate
xtabs(Count~stem+Corpus, data=dd) -> tb
```

What may well be muddying the waters, however, is that there are more recent coinings of the word with different senses from the geometric one "together in a line" (first known use in 1863 according to my dictionary); in these we'd naturally expect the form *colinear* just because people don't make up Latin words any more. Wikipedia has an article on [colinear maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colinear_map) & the on-line Merriam-Webster dictionary gives a second sense of [colinear](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colinear) (but not *collinear*), "having corresponding parts arranged in the same linear order", that finds its use in Genetics & Molecular Biology.

† If you really want to write *colinear* & anyone's picking on you because of it, ask them if they write *complanar*.

Comment: I listed the Oxford dictionary spellings as references that explicitly ascribe [colinear](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/colinear) as the US English spelling but also permits collinear as the spelling as well as the British reference to [collinear](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/collinear) that only admits one favored spelling.

Comment: @Carl: I'm not contesting that - I just don't see what *colinear* vs *collinear* has got to do with the different rules for doubling or not doubling a final *l* when you add a suffix. It's not as if Americans write *colaborate*, *colapse*, *colateral*, *colect*, *colide*, *coloquial*, *colude*, ...

Comment: American double "l" usage agrees with British on words that have the stress on the second syllable. Please read through the [spelling link](https://howtospell.co.uk/double-l-spelling-rule) provided.

Comment: @Carl: That begs the question of where the stress should go. I write *collinear* & put the stress on the 2nd syllable when I say it, as does everyone else I know (who has occasion to use the word); but I imagine people who write *colinear* put at least a secondary stress on the 1st syllable when they say it.

Comment: @Carl: You're misreading IPA there: the mark *precedes* the stressed syllable. When is *schwa* ever stressed anyway?

Comment: OK, I concede the emphasis for the pronunciation of collinear is (weakly) on the second syllable. All that does is make the spelling an exception to the rule, it does not change the spelling.

Comment: @Carl: Which spelling is an exception to which rule? I'm afraid I've lost track of what your point is: mine's just that the spelling *collinear* & pronunciation "co-LIN-ear" have the same explanation as the spelling *collaborate* & pronunciation "co-LAB-orate"; & that it's a quite separate one from that of the double *l* in *modelling*.

Comment: Generally, the /l/ is doubled for both American and British orthography when the emphasis is on the second syllable, where apparently the US English is an exception for the spelling /colinear/. Note, however, that US pronunciation is colinear/ˌkōˈlinēər/, whereas British is collinear/kəˈlɪnɪə/. That is, in US English there is more of an emphasis (the /,/) on the /co/ than in England.

Comment: @Carl: According to the site you've linked to, in the U.S. [*collinear*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/collinear) is pronounced /kəˈlinēər/ or /kəˈlɪniər/, & [*colinear*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/colinear) is pronounced /ˌkōˈlinēər/, as per my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70473/discussion-between-carl-and-scortchi).

Answer (score 3):

[Colinear](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/colinear) is a U.S. English spelling. In the U.S. "collinear", with two l's is also used. In British English, the [collinear](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/collinear) spelling would be the accepted form.

Another example of doubled versus single "l" appears in the word modelling (especially British) and modeling (especially U.S.). Multicollinearity versus multicolinearity follows this same pattern.

This general American versus British pattern for [spelling with one or two l's](https://howtospell.co.uk/double-l-spelling-rule) occurs for many words. However, "spelling" always has two l's. The divergence probably occurred during the 1800's during one of the U.S. [spelling reformations](http://www.historytoday.com/stan-carey/brief-history-english-spelling-reform).

The correct spelling is whatever fits the journal's style, and many journals insist on either American or British spellings. However, Canadian journals often accept both spellings.

When to use collinearity and when to use multicollinearity is discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/254896/99274). @whuber Indeed, we have discussed this before.

[Collinearity was first discussed](https://www.math.vt.edu/people/brown/doc/Comm_and_Coll_B.pdf) in the $3^{rd}$ century, and rediscovered 1500 years later.

Comment: I don't see 'model' as quite the same.  It's a verb in this context and has the "l" at the end.  I hope we can someday get rid of the "ll".  In writing I often use a hyphen to try to improve the situation: "co-linear" but I'm not sure it really does.

Comment: @FrankHarrell See the links provided, that will explain better than I can. There was one spelling reform, which originated in the US that the British did not want to follow that apparently got rid of the double letters. BTW, collinearity is more common 1,240,000 on google versus 251,000 for colinearity, so, you are probably fighting city hall.